# How to ensure there are no holes in my geometry?

Tags: geometry, faces

I have been given a geometry like the one in the picture but find that although it is a building, there appears to be holes in the façade...

[image: Fig1. Full building]

Is there any way of making sure there are no holes (see below) in it apart from looking at it very carefully and making faces?

[image: Fig 2. A hole]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the 3d print toolBox :

- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
- go to **Addons** and enable **3d print toolBox** and save the settings

[image]

- in the 3D view switch to ***Edit mode*** and select your mesh
- use the Non-Manifold operator ( press <kbd>T</kbd> to show the tools panel )
  [image]

Comment: Another great add-on for mesh checking is MeshLint: wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/MeshLint

Comment: Thank you for this!  It shows an aweful lot of holes! Is there a way of correcting these automatically? E.g. if the vertices are not that far apart?